# An attempt at using BASH scripting to login to git and eventually run git commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, login, git

I haven't been able to find anyone successfully attempt anything similar so here is my attempt.
I am trying to automate logging into GIT so later down the line I can run GIT commands.
The idea is:

git fetch

Username for 'https://github.com': "automatically input git username here"

Password for 'https://username@github.com': "Automatically input password here"

Output is git fetch.

My approach is to use 2 files. One that uses expect and send commands and one where the actual git command is run. This programmed looks like this.

./gitez

```
#!/bin/bash
git fetch
```

./t2

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./gitez
expect "Username for 'https://github.com': "
send "username"
```

My problem is when I execute this I get this output:

```
spawn ./gitez
Username for 'https://github.com': ron@ron:~/Desktop/cstuff/employee-management-system/bsh$
```

The problem seems to be that the **send** command is not working. I was wondering what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to solve the problem you have the wrong way. Can you use SSH and key-based authentication instead of HTTP?

Comment: Maybe but the issue remains the same in that I can seem to use ```send``` and ```git``` simultaneously.

Comment: I'd debug this by replacing my `git fetch` by a script that just `read`s a line from stdin and prints it out to see whether that is working. Generally, "strange" is not even a good word for the problem this seems to solve.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account#adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-account